# What is the name of $(\mathbb{Z}_2^s, \oplus, \odot)$ and where is it studied?

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, terminology, finite-rings, bit-strings

I'm studying the ring $(\mathbb{Z}_2^s, \oplus, \odot)$, where $s$ is arbitrary, $\oplus$ is the sum modulo $2$, and $\odot$ is the AND.

Does it have a name? Even for a certain fixed $s>1$? Does anyone know of a book that studies its properties? Thanks

Comment: I know that addition modulo 2 is used to sum games in game theory...

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{2^s}$?  How do you do AND with elements from that ring?  Do you mean $\mathbb Z_2^s$?

Comment: @rschwieb, to do an AND in my original ring, just express the numbers in binary. What I had written wasn't a typo but you are right anyway: it's clearer this way.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{2^s}$ suggests you are talking about $\mathbb Z/2^s\mathbb Z$ which does not have an AND operation (afaik) and doesn't have binary addition. So, many people will think it *is* a typo.

Comment: you are right. In fact I'm adding a new operation to $\mathbb{Z}_{2^s}$ via the homomorphism with the other ring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). Each element in this ring is a Boolean vector of length $s$.

Comment: I guess you answered first because your answer appears above the other one?

Comment: @GuillermoMosse The order of answers depends on the sort you have selected on your tab. Our answers were within a few seconds of each other.

Comment: OK, thanks. I ordered by time and I see yours was first. I'm accepting yours and upvoting theirs :-)

Answer (score 3):

It sure looks to me like you are talking about a finite [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring).  Every finite Boolean ring has this structure.

When the product is infinite, you still have a Boolean ring, but some Boolean rings are not just such a product. They are all subrings of such a product, though.